# Stocktwits API: Authentication 100% server-side

Tags: stocktwits

I can't seem to find any way to authenticate on Stocktwits entirely on the server-side, without requiring a redirect URL, meaning a client-side part.

Is there any way?

Answer (score 0):

Much like all the other social networks, we do require that the user be aware of the application and the access it requires, which can only be done client-side.  There are endpoints that do not require authentication, but otherwise you need to make sure the user knows your app is accessing their data.

We have considered offering a notification/accept option so that the client side can happen some time after your app requests access, and then once the user accepts, access is granted.  Is this something that would help out?